# Phonegap Native Code for Web service call or Ajax?

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile-website

I am creating a big app in phonegap, I just want to know which method is better to call web services

Is a simple ajax is enough or do we need to create cordova plugin to call the web service ?

Which one will use more memory and which one is fast ?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is better i think so. I used AJAX many times in my native applications to call web service. As compared to cordova plugin. AJAX works faster than cordova as of my knowledge. So i suggest you to use AJAX only.